# Jenkins Trigger Builds remotely in Pipeline

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I want to add to the Jenkins pipeline following configuration from the freestyle job:
[image]

in Pipeline I'm trying to use:

```
node {
    properties([pipelineTriggers([[$class: 'RemoteBuildConfiguration', remoteBuildToken: 'w6d7e8f4s']])])
}
```

but getting different errors like:

```
no known implementation of interface java.util.List is using symbol ‘pipelineTriggers’
```

Answer (score 0):

I can provide official docs here:

1. [trigger a remote parameterized job](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/Parameterized-Remote-Trigger/#stepclass-remotebuildconfiguration-trigger-a-remote-parameterized-job)
2. [parameterized remote trigger plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/parameterized-remote-trigger-plugin/blob/master/README_PipelineConfiguration.md)

I would suggest to use the step `triggerRemoteJob` instead of `properties([pipelineTriggers([...`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following syntax.

```
properties([pipelineTriggers([[$class: 'RemoteBuildTrigger', remoteBuildToken : '521456']])])
```

Comment: getting:
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: no known implementation of interface java.util.List is using symbol ‘pipelineTriggers’
IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate {triggers=@pipelineTriggers(<anonymous>=[{$class=RemoteBuildTrigger, remoteBuildToken=521456}])}